# Python - naming an instance of a class with a var value

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to instantiate a class object whose desired name is held in a variable that's created elsewhere.

I can't figure out how to make the instance of the class have the name held by the variable.

example:

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "bar"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = "a" # returned by another func.
    [string held by variable 'test'] = foo()
    print a.var1
```

Is this possible? (or even advisable...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not advisable, since it makes it difficult to program with the variable `a` when you do not know its name until run-time.

You might think about using a dict instead:

```
data = {}
test = func()   # "a"
data[test] = foo()
```

Comment: I was just running into that problem as I then thought about what I then wanted to do next with the class functions... hmmm. Time to re-think. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A function is probably better - that way the work you need to do is encapsulated and can be re-used:

```
def do_work(an_instance_of_foo):
    print an_instance_of_foo.var1

class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = "bar"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    do_work(foo())
```

If you also need the word, you can pass it to the function:

```
def do_work(an_instance_of_foo, my_word):
    # etc.
```

Alternately, you can use a dictionary as a namespace (as @unutbu has suggested) if you need the instance of `foo` to be associated with a particular name.